# Setup.py not found, ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, setup.py

I just installed ubuntu (Im new to this) through virtual box, and i wanted to download python, and then binwalk.

I checked with `python --version` and found out that python 3.10.7 is installed.

I then proceeded to do `sudo python3 setup.py install` like this page says (It's the first step): https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk/blob/master/INSTALL.md

It says: `can't open file 'home/username/setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

I tried to find solutions online, but nothing succeeded. Even when I try to delete and reinstall python, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: The instructions tell you what to do _after cloning_ or downloading the files in that specific project.

Comment: You must set your working directory to the cloned repo. The `setup.py`file otherwise won't be reachable when you invoke the `python3` command

Comment: Oh. How do I do that, if i may ask? I never really used github a lot before, im not that into it.

Comment: I wrote a quick answer, I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `setup.py` is a Python script of the repository ([this one](https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk/blob/master/setup.py)). When you do `python3 setup.py install`, you are telling your Python interpreter (`python3`) to execute the script `setup.py` with the argument `install`. However, the `setup.py` script must be in your working directory. Otherwise, the Python interpreter won't know what `setup.py` is. To do so. you must first clone the repo:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk.git
```

Then move to the new directory containing the cloned repo:

```bash
cd binwalk
```

And then install the Python package as told in the installation guide:

```bash
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Comment: Note that `sudo` creates a system-wide installation. Many times you probably want to avoid that.

Comment: True! That depends on your purpose. I guess that, being new to this world, if you are using a VM to try Python and this package, `sudo` is OK. Otherwise, you can opt it out.